# Ms Access. OleDbException: отсутствует значение для одного или нескольких требуемых параметров

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, ms-access

Формирую запрос на выборку следующим образом.

```
OleDbCommand SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM Посещения WHERE Дата Between dt_begin = ? and dt_end = ?", connection);

SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("dt_begin", OleDbType.Date).Value = new DateTime(2015, 6, 1);
SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("dt_end", OleDbType.Date).Value = new DateTime(2015, 6, 31);
```

После выполнения запроса получаю ошибку:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): отсутствует значение
>   для одного или нескольких требуемых параметров.

Первый параметр получает дату 01.06.2015. Второй - 30.06.2015. Про форматирование не уверен, но при неверном, должна была быть ошибка, связанная с форматом даты (точно).

Числа для проверки сам вбиваю в переменные. Название таблицы `Посещения`. `Дата` - название столбца. с ними проблем быть не может.

Так о чём, вообще, может идти речь? Как понимаю, здесь всего два параметра.

Comment: А разве `OleDbCommand` не поддерживает именованные параметры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё очень просто.

```
"SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Date Between ? and ?"
```

Comment: Пометьте свой ответ как верный.